# Format decimal to string

Tags: c#, decimal, string-formatting

How can I format this decimal: 123456789012345678
to a string "1.234.567.890,12345678"?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the decimal always that length?

Comment: What's the problem with the length?? It's a real issue.

Comment: How do you know where the decimal point should go?

Comment: @AndreMiranda, there is no problem with the length of the decimal, but if the decimal length is variable then it would change the format. For example, if I were trying to format `1` vs. `123456789012345678` and get the same output that would change the implementation.

Comment: This is a valid question.  My questions are the will the length of the  decimals always be the same?

Comment: -1. computers don't do magic - you need to specify exactly what you want unfortunately - so please update your question on why dots/commas in particular places. And yes, it is very hard to see results of "searched a lot" in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) for additional information about custom formats of numbers (of any type)

```
public string SpecialFormatDecimal(decimal input)
{
    return (input / 100000000).ToString("#,##0.00000000", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
}
```

A simple search on google showed the answer right away.

If you need local decimal point and thousand separator you can leave out the CultureInfo.

Answer (score 0):

Casperah answer is great, but don't forget, that you can use standard numeric format

```
public string SpecialFormatDecimal(decimal input)
{
    return (input / 100000000).ToString("N8");
}
```